# CSS Grid Display is Causing Tables to Have Disproportionate Heights

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-grid

In React, I am mapping tables, each with an unknown number of elements, into a container. Here is my css:

```
.markets-container {
  margin: 12.5px 0 0 0;
  min-height: 430px;
  max-height: 430px;
  overflow: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-column-gap: 10px;
}
```

Most of them look tidy, however there are cases when an element on the left (or right) changes height to match the element next to it. Look at the example of Over Under 0.5:

[image]

A more extreme example below:

[image]

Here is the relevant JSX:

```
 <Card.Body className="markets-container"> { filteredMarkets.map((market) => ( <Table size="sm" borderless={true} bordered key={market.cId}>
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th> {market.marketName} </th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody> {market.selections.map((selection) => ( <tr key={selection.id}>
         <td> {selection.name} </td>
         <td> { selection.price.toFixed(2) } </td>
       </tr> ))} </tbody>
   </Table> )) )} </Card.Body>
```

Is there a way to fix these unequal heights?

Answer (score 1):

You can try Flexbox too, just use properties from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Or you can try for Positions too, give the parent element relative, while the inner content absolute and give bottom, top, right or left.